# Installing wear/mobile app on android wear device does not work

Tags: android, mobile, installation

I have developed a android wear demo application. The Android wear description mentions that the wear application is automatically installed on the wear device when installed on the mobile device.

My problem is now that this does not work. The app was created with Android studio.

Wenn I start the waer (sided) app with debugging enabled it installs the app on the wear device and it works ok. Once I install the mobile app (which includes the waer app) the wear on the wear device is deleted, bit the waer not installed on the wear device anymore.

Same happens when I want to debug the apps. Whenever I debug the mobile app the app on the wear device is deleted but not installed.

As written the curios thing is that I can install the wear app directly from within Android stuudio.

All the settings look ok, created automatically by Android studio.

The mobile manifest looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.waldhoer.klemens.klemenswearsampleapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".KlemensActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".FallRecognitionService"  android:enabled="true"></service>
        <service android:name=".DataLayerListenerService"  android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

</manifest>
```

The wear manifest like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.waldhoer.klemens.klemenswearsampleapp" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
        <activity
            android:name=".KlemensWearActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".WearFallRecognitionService"  android:enabled="true"></service>
        <service android:name=".DataLayerListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" />

</manifest>
```

I also created a release version of the (mobile) app with Key signed, did not change anything.

Any idea what could be wrong? Thanks for help!

Comment: Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798599/syncing-mobile-app-to-android-wear?rq=1 I tried the tip with the Wear App and the resync option there. Now the app appears on my wer device. Curios. Hope this is the solution...

Comment: The problem with the debug version still remains. If I start debugging the mobile application the waer app is deleted but not again transferred to the wearable - making debugging quite uncomfortable.