# Android Wear app packing working in emulator?

Tags: android, apk, emulation, packaging, wear-os

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I am currently testing the Android Wear SDK and successfully developed my first wearable app using Android Studio. It is obviously part of a handheld app. This handheld app uses different product flavours for free and paid versions that have a different package names. In Android Studio the "development" package name is like com.abcde, while the flavours are com.abcde.free and com.abcde.pro.
The connection between wear app (dev package name is also com.abcde) and handheld is working fine so far, but I have problems with the packaging testing on the wear emulator.

My question: I have packaged the wear app into my release apk using the Gradle wearApp style in the first attempt and the manual style in the second attempt. Using the second attempt increases my apk by the size of the wear app!

However, I cannot see the app on the wear emulator after installing the release apk on my physical device (which is paired via adb forward with the wear emulator). Is this generally possible, or do I also need a physical wear device to test the automatic packaging?

Looking forward to answers. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this. It is a problem with the product flavors.

Let's say you have the following flavor configuration for example.

```
productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "com.myapp.free"
    }

    pro {
        applicationId "com.myapp.pro"
    }
}
```

You can package the wear app by adding this to your handheld apps build.gradle. This is for the pro version:

```
wearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'proRelease')
```

And this is for the free release:

```
wearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'freeRelease')
```

The solution was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24828264/547268

Comment: When I do wearApp project(path: ':wear', configuration: 'freeRelease') I have an error Error:(63, 0) Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'project()'!
Any idea about this ?

Comment: What Android Studio/Gradle version do you use? Maybe this was removed with the Gradle 2.0 update, because in the project where I had this problem I still use Android Studio 0.84 with Gradle 1.12.

Comment: I use IntelliJ not AS, first I was on gradle 1 but I put gradle 2 and same result. On my gradle file i have classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.+'

Comment: In gradle-wrapper.properties I have "distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip" and the same "classpath..." line in my gradle file. Works fine in my case.

Comment: Thanks I will try this !But with this solution you have to manually change your gradle file to the correct flavor :/ I see some other solution (didn't remind where) who you can put FlavorWearApp project(":wear", configuration:'flavor') Flavor2WearApp project(":wear", configuration:'flavor2')

Comment: just find the link :) it's here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74658