# Bug in android studio 2.2.x?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-studio-2.2

it was trying to build a newer version of a watchface. Android Studio upgraded to Version 2.2.
Since that, I have the problem, that the handheld-APK doesn't seem to have the wear-APK inside. If I install it via the play store (as a beta-release), I can see the app, which is for configuration, but the watchface is not pushed to the watch.
If I build the wear-APK alone, it is about 3 MB, the handheld one about 3.2 MB.
I googled a lot but only found one similar article here, but without a solution, only that it might be a bug in AS.
My watchface doesn't have a Activity, as I only use the service.
Can anyone help? Thanks!

This is what is in the wear-manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

and this in the mobile-manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Try to check your permissions. The handheld device needs to have all the permissions the Wear component has as stated in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24685845/5832311). After updating Android Studio to the latest version, try adding a missing permission to the Smartphone app. You can also check on this [forum](https://plus.google.com/+UmangKothari/posts/bmChpyQomZx).

Comment: Hey, @abielita,thank's for your answer!
I have read the thread but I think, I got everything right. I have edited the question with the permissions.

Comment: Solved it. I still don't know, if it is a bug or a feature, but you have to use configs for the flavors. If you don't have flavors, it should not be a problem at all.