# Wear App Doesnt install on watch when running a release build

Tags: android, wear-os, release

I am working on a watch app which also has a handheld app. Requirement is that watch app should install automatically onto watch once app is installed on the phone. But unfortunately, I am not able to get that done.

I know I need to do a release APK. I have been trying to do same but still not able to get it done. I also uploaded app on google play store to see if that can help me but still no luck can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong. Have been stuck on this for last few weeks any kind of help will be really appreciated.

Here is my Phone app gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    // office id
    applicationId "appid"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 8
    versionName "1.0.7"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':ImageGrid')
wearApp project(':wear')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.tf.library.tabs:tftabs:2.1.0'
compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.shaishavgandhi:login-buttons:0.1.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.2'
compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.picasso:picasso:2.5.2.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'

//CHAT UI
compile 'hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library:supernova-emoji-library:0.0.2'
compile 'me.himanshusoni.chatmessageview:chat-message-view:1.0.3'

// AUTH
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'

//DATABASE FIREBASE,UI
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'

//STORAGE FIREBASE
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.0'

//Places SERVICES
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'


compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
    //  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

```
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
compile 'com.victor:lib:1.0.1'
compile 'com.github.myinnos:AwesomeImagePicker:1.0.1'
compile 'com.adityak:browsemyfiles:1.4'
compile 'id.zelory:compressor:1.0.4'

compile files('libs/aspectjrt-1.7.3.jar')
compile files('libs/isoparser-1.0.6.jar')
```

}

And this is my wear app gradle file

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "appid"
    minSdkVersion 18

    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 7
    versionName "1.0.6"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.3'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
```

}

Just to make sure it work I have package name for both app and wearable same

Please help me on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24688363/5832311), try to check your permissions. The Smartphone part needs to have all the permissions the Wear component has.

You may also check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25104002/5832311) for reference.

> ...in **build.gradle** file of your phone app, you should mention the *exact name of the wear app folder*. If you created the project in *Android Studio*, then your build.gradle should look like this:
>
> ```
>                       wearApp project(':wear')
> ```
>
> This can happen because of the following reasons:
>
> - Wear & Mobile app's `"permissions"` are not same.
> - `Package name` of Wear & Mobile apps are not matching.
> - `Application ID` (build.gradle file) of Mobile & wear app are not matching.
> - Asset Compression

Hope this helps!

Comment: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

These are the only 2 things in my wear app manifest i have internet permission in my app too
Application ID is same Package name is same